# how to change my domain Name to new one in Ubuntu Apache PHP?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain, rename

I need help.
Currently I am using Ubuntu Apache server with PHP. 
My server name is some rt-arr-php. I want to change it to rtapp.arr.edu
Please help me.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

1. echo "rtapp.arr.edu" > /etc/hostname
2. /etc/init.d/hostname restart
3. add "127.0.0.1   rtapp.arr.edu  rtapp" in /etc/hosts
4. if use serveraname/serveralias directive in apache, change it
5. if use postfix: echo "rtapp.arr.edu" > /etc/mailname